# How to get all possible 2x2 sub matrices in a 3x3 matrix in C#?

Tags: c#, matrix, multidimensional-array

If matrix `A` of size (3x3), then should i use the method of finding determinants, like grabbing the rows and column of first element and removing it from the array 2D array to get the remaining elements and then moving to the next element and repeating the same steps ?

```
[{1,2,3},
 {4,5,6},
 {7,8,9}]
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What would you expect to get as the return value of said method?

Comment: i want to return the next 2x2 matrix as a submatrix, everytime i call that function ...

Comment: So, the first call should return `{{1,2}{4,5}}`, the next call should return `{{2,3},{5,6}}`, the call after that should return `{{4,5},{7,8}}` and so on?

Comment: yes that's correct!

Comment: Ok. So what have you tried so far?

Comment: @AliAbbas you can convert to array and take i, i + 1, i+3 ,i+4 elements, of course, you have to check if are not at the end of a row

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally was able to do it, here's what I did:

```
class program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[,] arr = new int[3, 3];
        Console.WriteLine("Enter elements of " + (arr.GetUpperBound(0) + 1) + "x" + (arr.GetUpperBound(1) + 1) + " matrix:");
        for (int i = 0; i < (arr.GetUpperBound(0) + 1); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < (arr.GetUpperBound(1) + 1); j++)
            {
                arr[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Matrix entered: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < (arr.GetUpperBound(0) + 1); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < (arr.GetUpperBound(1) + 1); j++)
            {
                Console.Write("\t" + arr[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Possible sub-matrices: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
           for (int j = 0; j< 3; j++)
             {
                TrimArray(i,j,arr);
             }    
        }

    }
    public static int[,] TrimArray(int row, int column, int[,] original)
    {
        int[,] resultant = new int[original.GetLength(0) - 1, original.GetLength(1) - 1];

        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < original.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            if (i == row)
                continue;

            for (int k = 0, u = 0; k < original.GetLength(1); k++)
            {
                if (k == column)
                    continue;

                resultant[j, u] = original[i, k];
                u++;
            }
            j++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
                for (int j = 0; j< 2; j++)
               {
                    Console.Write("\t"+resultant[i,j]);
               }
                Console.WriteLine();
        }
        return resultant;
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot showing matrix from code]

Answer (score 0):

I did this for you yesterday, I created a method that will return a square matrix, given a parent matrix and the length.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[][] parentMatrix = new int[][]
        {
            new int [] { 1, 2, 3 },
            new int [] { 4, 5, 6 },
            new int [] { 7, 8, 9 }
        };

        var chunks = GetSubMatrices(parentMatrix, 2);

        Console.WriteLine(chunks);
    }



    static List<int[][]> GetSubMatrices(int[][] parentMatrix, int m)
    {
        int n = parentMatrix.Length > m ? parentMatrix.Length : throw new InvalidOperationException("You can't use a matrix smaller than the chunk size");

        var chunks = new List<int[][]>();
        int movLimit = n - m + 1;

        var allCount = Math.Pow(movLimit, 2);


        for (int selRow = 0; selRow < movLimit; selRow ++)
        {
            for (int selCol = 0; selCol < movLimit; selCol ++)
            {
                // this is start position of the chunk
                var chunk = new int[m][];

                for (int row = 0; row < m; row++)
                {
                    chunk[row] = new int[m];
                    for (int col = 0; col < m; col++)
                    {
                        chunk[row][col] = parentMatrix[selRow + row][selCol + col];
                    }
                }

                chunks.Add(chunk);
            }
        }

        return chunks;
    }
```

If you have any problems using it, you can simply comment below.

Comment: Thanx alot man ! :) I actually figured it out too .. have look at it ..the code is posted above !

Comment: No I really don't see any problem in it .. your code also fulfills the demand of question !:)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to solve a problem like and came up with this answer. Hope it adds to your library of answers. If the submatrix specified is not greater than 1, do nothing.

```
public static void GetSubMatrixes(int[,] arr, int size)
    {
        int parentMatrixRowLength = arr.GetLength(0);
        int parentMatrixColLength = arr.GetLength(1);

        var overall = new List<object>();

        if(size > 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < parentMatrixRowLength; i++)
            {
                //get the columns
                for (int j = 0; j < parentMatrixColLength; j++)
                {
                    var subMatrix = new int[size, size];

                    /*if the new matrix starts from second to the last value in either the row(horizontal or column)
                     * do not proceed, go to the row or column in the parent matrix
                     * */
                    if (j < parentMatrixColLength - (size - 1) && i < parentMatrixRowLength - (size - 1))
                    {
                        //add 
                        for (int m = 0; m < subMatrix.GetLength(0); m++)
                        {
                            for (int n = 0; n < subMatrix.GetLength(1); n++)
                            {
                                /*check the sum of current column value and the sum of the current row value 
                                 * of the parent column length and row length if it goes out of bounds
                                 */
                                var row = i + m; var col = j + n;

                                //actual check here
                                if (row < parentMatrixRowLength && col < parentMatrixColLength)
                                {
                                    subMatrix[m, n] = arr[i + m, j + n];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        overall.Add(subMatrix);
                    }
                }
            }

            //display the sub matrixes here
            for (int i = 0; i < overall.Count; i++)
            {
                var matrix = overall[i] as int[,];

                for (int y = 0; y < matrix.GetLength(0); y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < matrix.GetLength(1); x++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", matrix[y, x]));
                    }
                    Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
```